# A function to check for hill or valley in a given list, without usage of Numpy or zip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

> A list of numbers is identified as 'hill' if it has an ascending sequence followed by a descending sequence. Similarly, it'll be 'valley hill' if it consists of a descending sequence followed by an ascending one. Each of the sequences should be of length of at least two.
>
> For example, a list `[1,2,3,5,4]` will be a hill or a list `[5,4,1,2,3]` will be a valley.

I'm trying to write a function, without the usage of either numpy arrays or zip function that returns a true if it identifies a hill or valley and false if it doesn't.

The code I've come up with is:

```
def hillovalley(n):
  if len(n)<=2:
    return False
  c = n[0]<n[1]
  x=0
  for i in range(len(n)-1):
    if c!=(n[i]<n[i+1]):
      c=n[i]<n[i+1]
      x=x+1
    if x==1:
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

However, this code would fail if the input is something like `[1,2,3,5,4,3,2,1]` or `[9,5,4,-1,-2,3,7]`.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you explain in words what your algorithm does? If you do that, maybe you'll eventually see where the logic flaw is... Also, I'm not even sure how zip would help, so why are you saying it would?

Comment: Similar code golf problem from earlier this week: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199055/mountain-range-numbers

Comment: Why do you need to change `c`? Oh, I see. You're exiting when `x == 1`. These variables could really use some nicer names, though. Also, you're exiting immediately when x becomes `1`... which happens the first time you encounter a different direction. Maybe check `x == 2` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do this:

```
def hillorvalley(seq):
    is_dec, is_inc = False, False
    inflections = 0
    for i in range(len(seq)-1):
        if inflections > 1:
            # Early stop if more than 1 inflection
            return False
        right = seq[i+1]
        middle = seq[i]
        diff = right - middle
        if diff > 0:
            if is_dec:
                inflections += 1
            is_inc = True
            is_dec = False
        elif diff < 0:
            if is_inc:
                inflections += 1
            is_dec = True
            is_inc = False
    if inflections == 1:
        return True
    return False

assert hillorvalley([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]) is False
assert hillorvalley([1, 1]) is False
assert hillorvalley([1]) is False
assert hillorvalley([1, 2, 3, 5, 4]) is True
assert hillorvalley([5, 4, 1, 2, 3]) is True
assert hillorvalley([1, 2, 3, 5, 5]) is False
assert hillorvalley([9, 5, 4, -1, -2, 3, 7]) is True
assert hillorvalley([1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]) is True
assert hillorvalley([9, -1, 4, -1, -2, 3]) is False
```

Comment: This could would pass for `[9, -1, 4, -1, -2, 3]` where it should fail. Each of the sequences should be of length of at least two.

Comment: I fixed it. It wasn't really clear to me from the question if it means there is just 1 hill or valley in the entire sequence or it is possible for multiple. Originally I assumed multiple, but now I guess it means just 1... which seems reasonable... given the geographical connotation.

Comment: Hi there. This is definitely the correct way to go. And yes, the sequence can have multiple hills or valleys. Anyways, thanks for this one! It's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

> an easy to understand solution for hillvalley problem.

```
enter code heredef hillvalley(l):
c=0
s=0
if(l[0]<l[1]):
    for i in range(1,len(l)):
        if(l[i-1]<l[i]):
            c+=1
    for i in range(c,len(l)-1):
        if(l[i]>l[i+1]):
            s+=1
    if(c>0 and s>0 and(s+c==len(l)-1)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
else:
    for i in range(1,len(l)):
        if(l[i-1]>l[i]):
            c+=1
    for i in range(c,len(l)-1):
        if(l[i]<l[i+1]):
            s+=1
    if(c>0 and s>0 and(s+c==len(l)-1)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

It fails on `[1,2,3,5,4,3,2,1]` because the condition

`c != (n[i] < n[i + 1])` is `False` where `c = True` and `(n[i] < n[i + 1]) = True`.
Then your `x=0`, therefore you return `False` with the else condition.

A code like this should do what you want:

```py
def hillovalley(n):
    diffs = []
    for i in range(len(n) - 1):
        diffs.append(n[i] < n[i + 1])
    first_value = diffs[0]
    if not first_value:
        diffs = [not d for d in diffs]
        first_value = True
        print('valley -> hill')
    else:
        print('hill -> valley')
    for i, diff in enumerate(diffs):
        if diff is not first_value:
            if i < 1 or sum(diffs[0:i]) != i:
                return False  # invalid
            else:
                if sum(diffs[i:]) == 0 and len(diffs) - i >= 1:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(hillovalley([1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]))  # True
    print(hillovalley([9, 5, 4, -1, -2, 3, 7]))  # True
    print(hillovalley([9, 5, 4, -1, -2, 3]))  # True
    print(hillovalley([9, -1, 4, -1, -2, 3]))  # False
```

Comment: Doesn't work on one of the cases listed: [1,2,3,5,4] -> False

Answer (score 0):

Using indexes isn't very pythonic and make the solutions look overly complex to me.  Here's a straightforward way to do it that leverages Python's features a little better:

```
def hillValey(A):
    if len(A)<3: return
    p1,p2,p3 = A[:3]
    for p in A[3:]:
        if p==p3 : continue
        if  p1==p2 or (p1>p2) == (p2>p3):
            p1,p2,p3 = p2,p3,p
        elif (p3>p) == (p2>p3) :
            p3=p
        else: return
    if p1==p2 or p2==p3:   return
    if (p1<p2) != (p2>p3): return
    return "Valley" if p1>p2 else "Hill"
```

Tests:

```
def check(A): print(A,hillValey(A))

check([1,2,3,5,4])
check([5,4,1,2,3])
check([1,2,3,5,4,3,2,1])
check([9,5,4,-1,-2,3,7])
check([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
check([1, 1])
check([1])
check([1, 2, 3, 5, 5])
check([9, -1, 4, -1, -2, 3])
check([3,2,2])
check([3,2,2,4])
check([3,3,2])
check([1,1,2])
check([1,1,2,1])
check([1,1,2,2,1])
check([1,1,1,2,2,1])
check([2,2,2,1,2,2])
```

Results:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4] Hill
[5, 4, 1, 2, 3] Valley
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] Hill
[9, 5, 4, -1, -2, 3, 7] Valley
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1] None
[1, 1] None
[1] None
[1, 2, 3, 5, 5] None
[9, -1, 4, -1, -2, 3] None
[3, 2, 2] None
[3, 2, 2, 4] Valley
[3, 3, 2] None
[1, 1, 2] None
[1, 1, 2, 1] Hill
[1, 1, 2, 2, 1] Hill
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1] Hill
[2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2] Valley
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def hillvalley(l):
    flag=[]
    inc=0
    for i in range(len(l)-1):
        if l[i]<=l[i+1]:
            flag.append(0)
        elif l[i]>=l[i+1]:
            flag.append(1)
    #print(flag)
    for j in range(len(flag)-1):
        if flag[j]<flag[j+1]:
            inc+=1
        elif flag[j]>flag[j+1]:
            inc+=1
    if inc==1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def hill(l):
        bol = 0
        count = 0
        for i in range(0,len(l)-1):
            if l[i+1] == l[i]:
                return False
            elif l[i+1] > l[i] and bol == 0:
                count = 1
            elif l[i+1] < l[i] and bol == 0:
                bol = 1
            elif l[i+1] > l[i] and bol == 1:
                return False

        if bol == 0 or count == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def valley(l):
        bol = 0
        count = 0
        for i in range(0,len(l)-1):
            if l[i+1] == l[i]:
                return False
            elif l[i+1] < l[i] and bol == 0:
                count = 1
            elif l[i+1] > l[i] and bol == 0:
                bol = 1
            elif l[i+1] < l[i] and bol == 1:
                return False
        if bol == 0 or count == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def hillvalley(l):
        if hill(l):
            print ("True")
            return True
        elif valley(l):
            print ("True")
            return True
        else:
            print("False")
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def ascending(l):
    if len(l) <= 1:
        return(True)
    else:
        return(l[0] < l[1] and ascending(l[1:]))

def descending(l):
    if len(l) <= 1:
        return(True)
    else:
        return(l[0] > l[1] and descending(l[1:]))

def hill(l):
    for i in range(1,len(l)-1):
        if ascending(l[:i+1]) and descending(l[i:]):
            return(True)
    return(False)

def valley(l):
    for i in range(1,len(l)-1):
        if descending(l[:i+1]) and ascending(l[i:]):
            return(True)
    return(False)

def hillvalley(l):
    return(hill(l) or valley(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two functions which address this problem nicely:

```
def hill(lst):
    lst = lst.copy()
    last = cur = float('-inf')
    while lst and last <= cur:
        last, cur = cur, lst.pop()
    while lst and last >= cur:
        last, cur = cur, lst.pop()
    return not lst


def valley(lst):
    lst = lst.copy()
    last = cur = float('inf')
    while lst and last >= cur:
        last, cur = cur, lst.pop()
    while lst and last <= cur:
        last, cur = cur, lst.pop()
    return not lst
```

Example:

```
>>> lst = [3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3]
>>> print(valley(lst), hill(lst))
True False
>>> lst = [3, 2, 1]
>>> print(hill(lst), valley(lst))
True True
>>> lst = [4, 2, 1, 4, 3]
>>> print(hill(lst), valley(lst))
False False
```

Note: these assume that for hill/valley it's ok to have the same number repeated twice.